# How do I isolate the subsystem causing these strange video graphics

Tags: video, html5-video

I have three browsers: netsurf, firefox, and epiphany.  Netsurf is displaying all types of graphics, in all sizes, very well.  Netsurf doesn't do video.

Epiphany is displaying only smaller jpeg, png and gif images. All images over about 150px are displayed with a triple-vision multiple image sort of effect, and are shown in gray instead of with color.  It doesn't seem to matter which graphic format the pics use.  They display the same way.  Epiphany doesn't do video (at least my older version does not do video).

Firefox (version 37) does the same as Epiphany, showing only smaller graphics correctly.  Firefox has HTML5 video. Videos from Youtube do the same kind of thing, with the triple-vision images, and gray-scale effects  instead of color.  Some videos are fine when the screen is small (if the viewer is only 200px or so wide).  This is not always true though - some videos show gray even if the viewer is small.

All of the graphics and videos show perfectly correctly for a fraction of a second when they are first loading.

Which of the libraries or dependencies of these browsers should I be scrutinizing for an answer?  Or something else entirely?